# FlatOut bonus races: what is the best angle to throw the driver?

Tags: flatout

[FlatOut](http://www.mobygames.com/game/flatout) racing game has a few [bonus races](http://www.mobygames.com/game/windows/flatout/screenshots/gameShotId,95280/) that include activities like *long jump*, *high jump*, *darts*, *bowling*... In such activities, the player must drive the car, then hold and release the nitro button. This will throw the car driver out of the window. While the button is held, the nitro meter (which will work as "angle meter") gets filled. How long the button is held determines the angle of the throw.

[image: A screenshot of the green angle meter]

The question is: **what is the best meter position in order to throw the driver?** Is the best angle the one when the meter is 100% filled, or is it when it's half-way?

By "best angle" I mean "the one that will throw the driver as higher and as further as possible", in order to win the *long jump* and *high jump* bonus races.

I'm playing on PC, but the game was also available on PlayStation and Xbox.

Answer (score 4):

I've played Flatout 2, which has the same stunts. Its meter displays how many degrees its at. I'm guessing this one doesn't =(

If they're at all similar, then each notch should be 10 degrees.

For the long jump, 45 degrees is ideal - Aim for just above the middle notch.

In the case of the high jump, it depends on the speed you're going at when you launch out of the car. Try 45 degrees - If you hit the "net" after you've stopped rising and started falling, then try launching at a lower meter position. If you hit the net before you reach the peak of your trajectory, then try launching at a higher meter position.

Answer (score 0):

100% has gotten me to 141.0 M. Push and hold the button at the base of the jump, then release when the meter is full.